# SD card with arduino UNO

Tags: arduino-uno, sd

I am trying to use a micro SD card in order to store data sent from an arduino UNO.
My setup consists of:

- Arduino UNO (5V logic), powered directly from USB cable
- [Digilent Full-sized SD Card Slot](https://store.digilentinc.com/pmod-sd-full-sized-sd-card-slot/)
- Simple microSD to SD adapter
- Transcend 4GB microSD card SDHC
- [TXB104 Logic Level Converter](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txb0104.pdf?ts=1587925861218)
- USB-powered PSU, that provides both the 3.3Volts and the 5Volts

The above components are connected as mentioned below:
Pins 1 to 4 of the Digilent SD module are driven to the 3.3Voltage side of the logic level converter. Also the SD module is powered with 3.3Volts. The 4 signals (SS, MOSI, MISO, SCK) are then taken from the 5Volt side of the logic level converter and are driven to the arduino UNO pins 10, 11, 12 and 13 respectively. Also, all the components have a common ground. The card is formatted to FAT32 using the [SD card Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter/eula_windows/index.html) from sdcard.org.

In the arduino, I upload the SdInfo sketch of the Sdfat library. The result I get is the following:

[image]

Let me know if I can provide any more info.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt the SDHC card is supported.

I don't have the same card slot reader, however, mine only worked with 'old' SD cards, not SDHC, SDXC etc.

So try an old one to see if it works (at least you rule out this option).